# Pushing Sub-array to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to use JS to build a JSON array that looks very much like this:

```
{  
   "someKey":"someValue",
   "lines":{  
         "1": {
            "someKey": "someValue"
         },
         "2" {
            "someKey": "someValue"
         },
   }

}
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var myArray = {
    someKey: "someValue",
    lines: []
};


var count = 0;  

$('.class_that_exists_twice').each(function() {

count ++;           

    myArray.lines[count] = {
    someKey: "someValue",
    };

});
```

However, the array that is returned looks wrong. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? (Please let me know if I should post the array as well)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sample isn't an array at all, it's an object literal. What is this to be used for? An actual array might be easier to work with

Comment: It's supposed to become a JSON array to use later in PHP, I forgot mentioning that I use `JSON.stringify` later in order to convert to a JSON array.

Comment: to do what in php, don't need to add index to javascript object as property key to use it as indexed array in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to create is not an array but an object. So it should be like this:

```
var myArray = {
  someKey: "someValue",
  lines: {}
};
```

The rest looks fine

Answer (score 1):

In the first JSON lines is an object. If you want to get your JSON to look like that you could do this:

```
var myArray = {
    someKey: "someValue",
    lines: {}
};

$('.class_that_exists_twice').each(function(index, obj) {         
    myArray.lines[index] = {
        someKey: "someValue",
    };
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g1pseum6/